# what is the best way to template head tag with angular 2

Tags: angular

i want to know what is the best way for template head tag with angular 2?
for example i have a list of videos and want when user click on the any video some title of video get sit in to the title tag.
i have some idea like create a service and use in another components like this :

```
   import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Title} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

    @Injectable()
    export class SEOService {

        private _default: any;
        private _head: Element;

        constructor(private _title: Title) {
            this._head = document.querySelector('head');
        }

        public setDefault(model: any) {
            this._default = model;
        }

        public update(model: any) {
            var title = this._default.title + (model.title ? ' | ' + model.title : '');
            var desc = model.description || this._default.description;

            this._title.setTitle(title);

            this.setMeta('description', desc);
            this.setMeta('keywords', model.keywords || this._default.keywords);


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the page title there is the [Title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html) service. For other meta tags and other global stuff there is additional support planned but currently the title service is the only piece available.

Just import the `Title` class and use its `getTitle()` and `setTitle()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, it currently does not work with server-side rendering though.

Comment: I don't use server-side rendering. Why do you think it's not working? SSR is one of the main reasons for its very existence (besides web workers)